# SQL Server running total by date and and another column

Tags: sql-server

I'm having trouble trying to work out how to generate a running total by date and another column.

I can create a running total using sum over on a simple table but in this case doing the joins and also doing the running total by date is beyond my abilities to be honest.

This is all in a SQL Server database on Azure (version 12).

The source data tables are as follows:

[image: Existing tables]

`REFERENCEDATA_DATES` is a table of dates covering all of the entry dates and the corresponding end of month date. It can be joined with `Entry_Date` in `ERP_GLDATA`.

`Date` and `EOM` are `date` type columns.

`ERP_JOBHEADERS` is a list of all jobs in the system and the related company number. `Job_Number` in this table can be joined with `Job_No`. in the `ERP_GLDATA` table.

`Company_No.` and `Job_Number` are `VARCAR(MAX)` type columns.

`ERP_GLDATA` is the entry information. It should be noted that each job does not necessarily have an entry on every date, or even in each month, or at all.
`Entry_Date` is of `Date` datatype, and `Account_No.` & `Job_No.` are `VARCAR(MAX)` and `TotalBase` is `Decimal` type.

The desired output is as follows:

[image]

Effectively the output should produce a running total of the entries on each job up to and including end of month date on the `REFERENCEDATA_DATES` table. The example also shows that it should still return a number even when there are no actual entries in that month on that job. Hopefully the image makes things clear.

The only other issues is the `ERP_GLDATA` table needs to be filtered so `Account_No. = 10000` only.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction (assuming this is even possible in SQL)?

Many thanks in advance.

Efficiency of the query is not a concern in this situation (as long as it runs I suppose!).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample query. You may change the base date and base value for the jobs. Effectively, base date is the first date in the reference dates table.

```
SELECT jh.Company_No,
        jh.Job_number,
        rd.EOM,
        Sum(totalbase)
  FROM [dbo].[ERP_JOBHEADERS] jh
  cross apply (select [Entry_date]
                     , TotalBase
                     ,[Job_no] from [dbo].[ERP_GLDATA]  where jh.Job_number=Job_no
                Union
                Select   
                     '2016-01-01'  -- base date 
                     , 0            -- base value
                     ,Job_number from [dbo].[ERP_JOBHEADERS] where jh.Job_number=Job_number
                     ) gl
  left join [dbo].[REFERENCEDATA_DATES] rd on rd.[date]>=gl.Entry_date
group by jh.Company_No,
        jh.Job_number,
        rd.EOM
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query with filter on Account_no:

```
SELECT jh.Company_No,
        jh.Job_number,
        rd.EOM,
        Sum(totalbase)
FROM [dbo].[ERP_JOBHEADERS] jh
cross apply (select [Entry_date]
                     , TotalBase
                     , Account_No
                     ,[Job_no] 
                    from [dbo].[ERP_GLDATA] 
                    where jh.Job_number=Job_no
                Union
                Select   
                     (select top 1 [date] from [dbo].[REFERENCEDATA_DATES] order by [date] asc)  -- base date 
                     , 0            -- base value
                     , AcctNo.AccountNo
                     ,Job_number 
                     from [dbo].[ERP_JOBHEADERS]  erp_jh
                        outer apply (select top 1 ISNULL(Account_No,0) as AccountNo 
                                                        from [dbo].[ERP_GLDATA] 
                                                        where Job_no=erp_jh.Job_number) AcctNo

                     where jh.Job_number=Job_number
                     ) gl
  left join [dbo].[REFERENCEDATA_DATES] rd on rd.[date]>=gl.Entry_date

where Account_No=10000

group by jh.Company_No,
        jh.Job_number,
        rd.EOM
```